# jQuery UI Resizable in CKEditor

Tags: javascript, jquery, ckeditor

I am trying to get a  within a CKEditor instance working with jQuery UI Resizable.

I use the following code to setup jQuery UI Resizable:

```
var ckinstance = CKEDITOR.instances.ckeditor-1;
ckinstance.on("instanceReady", function() {
    $(ckinstance.document.$).find(".gallery").resizable();
});
```

This seems to half work. If I inspect the HTML within the CKEditor instance the div has all the jQuery UI Resizable tags for handles etc but the div doesn't seem to be able to resize.

Does anyone know why the div won't resize?

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand why jQuery UI Resizable. CKEditor already has own resizing API:

- [editor.resize()](http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.editor.html#resize) for resizing on-demand
- [config.resize_enabled](http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.config.html#.resize_enabled), [config.resize_maxHeight](http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.config.html#.resize_maxHeight), [config.resize_maxWidth](http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.config.html#.resize_maxWidth) and so on - to control resizing process

Perhaps you should better rethink your goal. Anyway, if you really want to use jQuery UI, consider this HTML:

```
<div id="resizable" style="overflow: hidden;">
    <textarea id="editor1">
        Initial content
    </textarea>
</div>
```

And the following JavaScript:

```
(function( $ ) {
    var editor = CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1', {
        width: '100%',
        resize_enabled: false       // Disable native CKEditor resize.
    });

    $( "#resizable" ).resizable({
        resize: function( event, ui ) {
            editor.resize( '100%', ui.size.height - 2 );        // Play with this.
        }
    });
})( jQuery );
```

Editor will be automatically adjusted to your `#resizable` container. If the performance is crucial (old browsers), consider using the [stop event](http://jqueryui.com/demos/resizable/#event-stop) instead.

Have fun!

Comment: Sorry, I didn't explain myself properly. There is a <div> within CKEditor which I want to be able to resize. I don't want to use jQuery UI to resize the editor, rather I wan't to be able to resize a div contained within CKEditor.

Comment: Michael, have you ever found a solution for that. Same requirement here.