# How to make ckeditor scrollable when content grows?

Tags: javascript, scroll, ckeditor

I set:

```
CKEDITOR.config.height = viewport.height() + 83;
CKEDITOR.config.fullPage = true;
CKEDITOR.config.resize_enabled = false;
CKEDITOR.config.maxHeight = viewport.height() + 83;
```

but when I enter a lot of text, the whole editor grows instead of just scrolling. Because it does not scroll, the "whole page moves up" and cannot be scrolled back again. I looked through the docs but cannot find anything.

Comment: You can try this solution : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11504826/how-to-set-and-lock-the-ckeditor-window-size

Comment: thx. I already tried that but it doesn't work for me.

Comment: Do you use inline editor? Normal, classic editor like in the [demo](http://ckeditor.com/demo) has normal scrollbar. Please make your question clearer, because now it misses the minimum required information to understand it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to the settings I mentioned above, the removal of plugins was the key.

Solution:

```
CKEDITOR.config.fullPage = false;
CKEDITOR.config.resize_enabled = false;
CKEDITOR.config.removePlugins = 'resize,autogrow';
```